# How to sort an array of objects by a string value in the object properties?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have been learning swift recently (I have used js and java before), and I ran into this problem where I need to sort an array of objects by a string value in the object. I have this list and I want to add a sort feature, where it automatically sorts the list by the date of the logged dates (It is kind of like a reading log). So here is how I built the array behind the log:

```
struct LogItem: Hashable, Codable {
    var date: String
    var time: String
    var message: String
}
```

And in the LogView struct I have:

```
@AppStorage("logs") var logs: [LogItem] = []
```

The message property is kind of notes on the log btw. So what I want to do is sort this array by the date property, which is in the "d/mm/yyyy" format. I have looked at a few solutions but couldn't figure out how to sort it in alphabetical order if it is in a object.

If someone could please help that would be great, also some of the posts I have seen only seem to work in a swift playground and not in an actual swiftui file, I get the cannot use instance member within property initializer error, property initializers run before 'self' is avaliable. So it will have to work in an actual app.

Comment: `x/xx` is ambiguous. Nevertheless both `d/mm/yyyy` and `m/dd/yyyy` string formats are not sortable. You can sort yyyy/mm/dd or convert the strings to `Date`

Comment: Your date format, which I guess when you say ""x/xx/xxxx", is year at the end, isn't compatible with a simple String sort. I'd create a `lazy var dateDate: Data` that is a `Date` representing the `date` & `time` (my naming could be better, I admit). And then, use that one to sort.

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion, I changed the format to d/mm/yyyy in my post

Comment: but how do I sort it?

Comment: As Larme and I said, you can't, please note *are not sortable* and *isn't compatible with a simple String sort*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort an array of custom objects like this. Keep in mind that this method sorts the strings alphabetically.

```
logs.sort(by: {$0.date < $1.date})
```

Switch the `<` to a `>` to reverse the sort order.

---

> ... some of the posts I have seen only seem to work in a swift playground and not in an actual swiftui file, I get the cannot use instance member within property initializer error, property initializers run before 'self' is avaliable. So it will have to work in an actual app.

Your problem here is you are putting the code in the wrong place. It should be in the `onAppear` method, placed after your outermost view:

```
.onAppear {
    logs.sort(by: {$0.date < $1.date})
}
```

For example:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView { // <- Just an example
        ...
    }
    .onAppear {
        // appear stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: I put the onAppear right under the var body: some View but it gives me error: cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'onAppear'

Comment: @Evman Put it right above that - move it one curly brace up. See my updated answer for details.

Comment: You are quite welcome.